# Firefox adds undesired thin line above a logo animated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

Well it seems that I'm having some sort of a problem with Firefox, I've added a logo to my website and styled it through this CSS block:

```css
#splash div.logo > a {
  background-image: url("../../---.png");
  background-size: 280px;
  height: 85px;
  width: 280px;
}
```

When I open the web page with Chrome or any other browser other than Firefox it displays it in the right way,unless I zoomed in it will show a thin line,
while opening the web page from Firefox will show a thin line above the image with or without zooming in.

The Logo is animated through this code:

```
IndexPage: {

    Splash: {
        init: function() {
            var $splash = $('#splash'),
                $logo = $splash.find('#logo'),
                frame = 1,
                frameCount = 46
                framesPerSecond = 50;

            function animateLogo() {

                var lastTime = 0;
                var currTime = new Date().getTime();
                // var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
                var timeToCall = 25;

                if (typeof requestAnimationFrame == "undefined")
                    requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
                        return setTimeout(function () { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, timeToCall);
                    };

                if (frame <= frameCount) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        requestAnimationFrame(animateLogo, $logo);
                        $logo.css('background-position', '0 -' + (frame * 85) + 'px');
                        frame += 1;
                    }, timeToCall);

                    // lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
                }
             }

             $('form.search').on({
                 close: function() { $splash.removeClass('searching'); },
                 open: function() { $splash.addClass('searching'); }
             });


             if ($window.width() >= 532) {
                 $window.scroll(function() {
                     var top = $window.scrollTop();
                     $splash.find('div.logo').css('opacity', top > 150 ? 0 : (150 - top) / 150);
                 });
             }


             $window.resize(function() {
                 if ($splash.width() < 768) {
                     $logo.css('background-position', '0 0');
                 } else {
                     $logo.css('background-position', '0 -3910px');
                 }
             });

             if ($window.width() >= 768) 
                 animateLogo();
        }  
    }
}
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: can you give a demo?

Comment: what type of a demo, I've attached images above, Do you need more code? even tho i don't think its a code mater, i think it is rendered incorrectly by firefox engine.

Comment: sorry that was by mistake, ive removed it :)

Comment: Long shot, but its not the focus highlight applied by Firefox is it? Have you tried setting focus elsewhere (i.e. clicking elsewhere on the page) to see if that solves it? Very difficult to tell what it is from who images like that. A link to the site would help enormously

Comment: Have you tried zooming in on Chrome to see if the thin line appears at 150% / 200%?

Comment: @LDJ yeah i've tried that and its not the focus, sorry tho i can't provide you with a link to the website

Comment: @DavidWilkinson yeah i did that, there is no thin line at all in chrome

Comment: You’re scaling your image here – so what are the original dimensions of the image? Might be due to simple rounding differences, that are handled differently by browsers. Maybe using `background-size:contain` or `cover` might yield a better result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [firefox adds undesired thin line above a logo animated using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35600473/firefox-adds-undesired-thin-line-above-a-logo-animated-using-javascript)

Comment: I am not sure but could you try using normalize.css? download here: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Comment: For me it looks like you need to normalize styles cross browser .

Comment: Your url would help in order to take a closer look not just at the code but the logo too.  I am not sure if you reduced the images that you posted but something seems off. Your CSS has a image width of 280px while the mysterious line is only about 200px in width.  May be a clue to figuring out what the problem could be.  What is your url?

Comment: @user1724434 those arn't the used images those are jus for demonstration purposes the original image has  no back ground for animation i'll add it to the q later tonight

Comment: May be you can check if there is shadow or not

Comment: Is your browser zoom set to 100%? This can sometimes create these scaling lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Firefox does some extrapolation of your image before rendering it (for perf I guess). It calculate the pixel to display using the neighbourhood of the one on your image, and some pixels on the top of your image are near black pixel resulting in a black/grey line.

**EDIT: You can disable this behavior using `image-rendering: optimizequality;` in your CSS.**

*Snippet to test this:*

```js
var frame = 1,
frameCount = 46;
function animateLogo() {
    $logo=$('.logo');
    var lastTime = 0;
    var currTime = new Date().getTime();
    var timeToCall = 25;

    if (typeof requestAnimationFrame == "undefined") {
        requestAnimationFrame = function (callback, element) {
            return setTimeout(function () {
                callback(currTime + timeToCall);
            }, timeToCall);
        }
    }
    if (frame <= frameCount) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            requestAnimationFrame(animateLogo, $logo);
            $logo.css('background-position', '0 -' + (frame * 85) + 'px');
            frame += 1;
        }, timeToCall);
    }
}
```

```css
.logo {
  background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,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');
  background-size: 280px;
  height: 85px;
  width: 280px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="logo"></div>
<button onclick="frame=0;$('.logo').css('image-rendering','auto');animateLogo()">Without CSS property (default)</button>
<button onclick="frame=0;$('.logo').css('image-rendering','optimizeQuality');animateLogo()">With CSS property</button>
```

*Old answer:
You can separate sprites on your image by a few transparent pixels (or of the color of what is behind your logo) so the effect would not be visible anymore.*

Answer (score 0):

Well, if all else fails, you could always attempt to place a div over the thin line. Also try adding a *border* attribute to your code and set it to 0px solid *whatever your background-color is*. If all of these don't work, then try adding another border over the red line.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the image as is in the browser and check if the line is still placed. Also, in Firefox, right-click, choose inspect and see where it points to. For example, the line might be coming from div or some other html element.

Answer (score 0):

i think creating an empty 'content' and using a background to show the image: works nicely in Chrome, Firefox, Safari and IE8+9

```
.googlePic:before {
    content: '';
    background: url('../../img/googlePlusIcon.PNG');
    margin-top: -6.5%;
    padding-right: 53px;
    float:right;
    height: 19px;
}
```

you could try if this would fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think it just renders the size of image or block incorrectly, I played on your website with the CSS and and it seems that if you change background size to

```
background-size: 279.8px auto;
```

it solves the issue.

**UPDATE:**

As an additional solution, you might wrap the logo in a div, give the div hidden overflow, and then lift the block with your image up to 1px. It will hide the line as well.

Answer (score -1):

Try like this:

```
#match div.logo > a {
    background-image: url("../../---.png");
    background-size: 280px;
    height: 85px;
    width: 280px;
    outline: 0;
}
```